# Large difference between different classification algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, svm, random-forest, logistic-regression, naivebayes

EDITED:

I have a classification dataset of 350000 rows and 500 features. The features are a Tfidf vector.
While my Y(predictor) has values from 1-16 to classify the sentences into 16 types.

The training and testing are randomly split

When I send my data through a classification algorithm, I'm getting a huge difference between the accuracy :

SVM and Naive Bayes are giving 20%+ (which is too less)

RandomForest gives around 55% accuracy which seems more accurate but is still less

Is there a reason why I'm getting such a huge difference across different algorithms and is there a way to further increase the accuracy?

I'm trying predict a person's personality through his tweets

Comment: Logistic Regression doesn't seem to fit your problem though, it is usually used for binary problems. It wouldn't fit properly to a polynomial of that degree. Random Forests or SVM on the other hand could get 95% accuracy depending on the problem set. So I don't see any problem (well 95% accuracy is high but it depends). You should give more detail, like where is that accuracy from, test set? Did you train on test set or did you leave_one_out. Also you could get better answers on this kind of question from [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How do you compute accuracy? Have you tried cross-validation?

Comment: I have updated the question. 
My accuracy fell way below after I discovered a flaw in my training data. It was considering my Y array along with the X input only, so was getting 95% accuracy. Now the accuracy has dropped way below